# I have made a resource in eclipse and want to pull an image from it to my startingclass

Tags: java, image, package, assets

essentially I want to make it so an image called lovesprite appears over the background. I want to just pull it from the package in the project called data.
I have done something similar following a tutorial but it doesn't seem as straight forward as i remember. any help would be appreciated.

```
package scoreboard;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
//private URL base;
import scoreboard.StartingClass;
public class StartingClass extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("/scoreboard/src/data/lovesprite.png");
private URL base;
private static Image lovesprite;
//public StartingClass() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    //JLabel blueLabel = new JLabel("a");
    //blueLabel.setOpaque(true);
    //blueLabel.setBackground( Color.BLUE );}
@Override
public void init() {

    super.init();
    setSize(1000, 800); // window size
    setBackground(Color.GREEN); // sets BG as green
    setFocusable(true); // applet takes focus when game begins, this does
                        // not enable unless you are with applet
    addKeyListener(this);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent(); // assigns the
                                                        // window of app to
                                                        // frame
    frame.setTitle("wimbledon scoreboard"); // assigns title
        // TODO: Handle exception

    //URL base;
    lovesprite = getImage(base, "/scoreboard/src/data/lovesprite.png");
    new ImageIcon("/scoreboard/src/data/lovesprite.png");
    }
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(lovesprite(), 180, 110, this);
    paint(g);}
private Image lovesprite() 
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("/scoreboard/src/data/lovesprite.png");
```

Should actually be...

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/scoreboard/src/data/lovesprite.png"));
```